# SVG canvas, axis and coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, svg

I'm new to SVG.

I am trying to set a canvas to be 100% in width (of the browser window). No problem there.

For the x axis, the 100% width will be equivalent to 10 seconds.

For the y axis I would would like to to use millimeters for the units.

My data looks something like this:

```
x (sec)     y (μV/mm)
0           1.898876286
0.001953    0.987415571
0.003906    -1.898876286
0.005859    -4.139550286
0.007813    -0.911460571
0.009766    1.822921286
0.011719    1.974831286
0.013672    7.36764
0.015625    6.570112
0.017578    4.291460286
0.019531    1.519101
0.021484    -2.962247
0.023438    -4.215505429
.... many more .......
```

My goal is to make a line graph with this data.

Can someone get me started on the right path to make this?

---------- EDIT ----------

I've modified the data above slightly to make it more understandable. I'm using an SVG path to draw the data as follows:

```
<svg width="100%"  height="100%">
<path d="M0,1.898876286
        L1.001953,0.987415571
        L2.003906,-1.898876286
        L3.005859,-4.139550286
        L4.007813,-0.911460571
        L5.009766,1.822921286
        L6.011719,1.974831286
        L7.013672,7.36764
        L8.015625,6.570112
        L9.017578,4.291460286
       style="stroke:#660000; fill:none;" />    
</svg>
```

My question is how do I define the units for the x and y axis of an SVG?

The x axis values of my data are seconds. The y axis are millimeters.

100% of the screen width should be equivalent to 10 seconds, therefore 10% of the screen width would be equivalent to 1 second.

The y axis should interpret the data as millimeters.

I would then expect the above data to be drawn as a horizontal wavering line across the entire browser screen, and the height of the wave (amplitude) to range between approximately -4 and 7 millimeters.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: If you are going to be making graphs/charts/etc with svg in the future I would highly suggest looking at the D3 javascript library

Comment: yes I'm actually going to do everything in D3.js but I'm trying to get a basic understanding of how SVG works first. Any pointers on how I would have to set up the SVG axis, canvas and coordinates to work with data like this?

Comment: Can you narrow your question for us, @Charlie?

Comment: I have edited my post with clarifications. Thanks!